# Java - Having the same reference in multiple class

Tags: java, reference, instance

how to make references to the same instance in multiple objects?

Let say I have Class A :

```
Class A{
    public A relative = null;
    public int number = 0;
}
```

and I will create multiple A and those A's relative will be a reference to one of those A.

For example:
Let's create four A, so now we have A1, A2, A3, A4.

And the following map will shows (Left Hand Side)'s relative is making reference to (Right Hand Side)

```
A1 => null,
A2 => A1,
A3 => A1,
A4 => A2
```

What I want to achieve is: 
When I modified A1 by (A2.relative.number = 1), and will also "apply" to A3's relative (Which supposed to be a reference to the same instance A1)

So, here are what I have tried:

1. Using setter:

   ```
   public void relateTo(A relative){
       this.relative = relative;
   }
   ```

   This doesn't works, since Java is passing reference by value. Where the relative inside the scope of this method is just a copy. So whenever I make any changes to it from outside, it doesn't make changes to this.
2. Public the variable and direct access it

   ```
   A2.relative = A1;
   ```

   But nope, this doesn't works.

I have no idea how to achieve this, any ideas?

Comment: It would *really* help if you'd show a short but complete example. If A2 and A3 both refer to A1, then it really *should* be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I modified A1 by (A2.relative.number = 1), and will also "apply" to A3's relative (Which supposed to be a reference to the same instance A1)

This principle is simlpy achieved by making two references point at the *same object*

**Example**

```
A a1 = new A();
A a2 = new A();
A a3 = new A();

a2.relative = a1;
a3.relative = a1;
// Now both a2 relative and a3 relative point to the same A object.
```

Now if I make a change to `a2` relative, say

```
a2.relative.number = 2;
```

Then `a3` relative will have also changed.

**Why?**

This is because, when you declare an object, you're actually handling the *pointer* to that object; not the object itself. What the code above does, is create *one* relative, and make *two* classes *point* to it.

[image]

*Observe my beautiful artwork*

Answer (score 1):

> This doesn't works, since Java is passing reference by value. Where the relative inside the scope of this method is just a copy. So whenever I make any changes to it from outside, it doesn't make changes to this.

Did you try this?

Java passes object references by value; any changes made to those references affect the object in question. Similar to passing pointers in other languages.